# Array spacing in multiple line environment

Tags: spacing, arrays

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} \\
  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} \\
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

The first `gather` produces two arrays; in the first, the fractions are properly spaced, while in the second, they are crowded together with the default vertical spacing. Why do I need to re-specify `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` after the newline? Is there a better way to do this? (I realize I could enclose the whole gather inside a `{}` pair with a `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` after the opening `{`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each entry between line breaks inside the `gather` environment are placed inside a group. To that end, the scope of `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` only lasts until the end `\\`, after which you have to issue it again.

A very similar problem is showcased when you use, for example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \bfseries ABC DEF \\
  GHI KLM
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The **bold** switch (`\bfseries`) doesn't span further than `\\`, and would have to be re-issued to have an effect.

For the stretch to have a global effect *across* line breaks, you have to issue it outside the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Voila:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

{  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % PS
\begin{gather*}
%  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} \\
  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
} % PS

\begin{gather*}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} \\
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The results are the same, because `\arraystretch` is set for every occurence inside the group (i.e. between lines marked PS in our case).

Comment: Right. As I said in the original post, I realize that this is a solution. I'm trying to understand why the system behaves as it does. Thanks.